# download pdf file from outside glassfish container

Tags: pdf, primefaces, download, glassfish

I'm trying to download pdf file created by another application and stored in a folder (D:\forDownload\pdfs) which are outside of my web container (Glassfish).
I'm using primefaces 8.0 RC1 and windows server 2012

Answer (score 0):

pb solved with this:

```
        File file = new File("D:\forDownload\pdfs\\"+bean.getCode()+".pdf");            
        InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] buf = new byte[204800];
        int offset = 0;
        int numRead = 0;  
        while ((offset < buf.length) && ((numRead = fis.read(buf, offset, buf.length - offset)) >= 0)) 
        {
          offset += numRead;
        }
        fis.close();

        HttpServletResponse response =
           (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
               .getExternalContext().getResponse();

        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+bean.getCode()+".pdf");
        response.getOutputStream().write(buf);
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
        response.getOutputStream().close();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
```